# Interpreting data from a json that was imported into a CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, data-structures

I have a csv file that was created from a json. My first column is my key.  The first column only has unique values. Then the subsequent values in the rows are identifying codes of attributes that belong to my key value. For any given row the number of attributes listed in each row ranges from 1 attribute value that belongs to the key to up to 25 different attribute values. The attribute values are listed in no descernable order.

An example of this would be:
[image: Sample data:]

So in this example, I basically want to understand how many times "1289679" shows up in the data, but I need to do it for every single one of the attribute values that appear in this file.

I really haven't tried anything yet, because I'm normally used to using structured data with specific columns vs. what I have here. So basically the output I am looking for would be:

[image: Output I am looking for.]

Comment: Please post text data as *text* not images so we don't have to reinvent your data manually.  SO is not a coding service, so you should make an attempt yourself and post the code and describe any problems encountered.

Comment: what if attribute appears three times in a single row? does that count as three or one?

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:csvhelper] which is a ***.NET library** that allows for easy reading and writing of comma-separated values (CSV) files.*  So are you looking for a solution in C#/.NET, or something else like Python?

Answer (score 1):

The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) make this pretty straightforward.  [Extended Iterable Unpacking (PEP 3132)](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) helps with the variable row size:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('input.csv', newline='') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    header = next(reader)  # skip header
    # "id" will be the first column in the row.
    # "attributes" will be a list of the remainer of the row.
    for id, *attributes in reader:
        counter.update(attributes)
        #counter.update(set(attributes))  # to only count once per row if needed

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow(['Attribute Value', 'Count of Appearances'])  # header
    for attribute, count in counter.items():
        writer.writerow([attribute, count])
```

input.csv (contrived example since data was an image):

```
ID,Attributes
abc,1,2,3,3,3,3
bcd,2,3,4
cde,4,5,6,7,8
def,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

output.csv:

```
Attribute Value,Count of Appearances
1,2
2,3
3,6
4,3
5,2
6,2
7,2
8,2
9,1
10,1
```